# Template associated with nested route not rendering in parent template

Tags: ember.js

Here are my HTML templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <p>Application template</p>
    {{#linkTo employees}}<button>Show employees</button>{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="employees">
    <p>Employees template</p>
    {{#linkTo employees.employee}}<button>Show employee</button>{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet employeeOutlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="employee">
    <p>Employee template</p>
</script>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('employees', function () {
        this.route('employee');
    });
});

App.EmployeeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('employee', {       // the template to render
            into: 'employees',          // the template to render into
            outlet: 'employeeOutlet',   // the name of the outlet in that template
            controller: 'employee'      // the controller to use for the template
        });
    }
});
```

JS Bin [**here**](http://jsbin.com/izoviw/1/edit)

I added a lot of unnecessary code in order to try to get the employee template to render in the outlet of the employees template (e.g., naming the outlet, defining the renderTemplate method...), but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the employee template to employees/employee and it will work.  Otherwise you need to tell the view to use the employee template.

example
http://jsbin.com/ukajix/1/

Comment: Alright, thanks. Although I did go through the documentation a couple of times, I can't remember the exact spot where they talk about this. I also find it somewhat strange that you need to name the template that way (i.e., including the path). After all, these pieces of codes are templates that are meant to be reused.

Comment: Here is the link to the docs on the naming conventions. http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/#toc_nesting